# combobox databinding by JsonConvert in winforms C#

Tags: c#, json, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I had to set the properties of the combobox in the designer.

- combobox property

  - DataSource    : dataSet_code
  - DisplayMember : table1.code_desc
- combobox work

  - Use data bounding items  : check
  - DataSource : dataSet_code
  - Show Member : table1.code_desc
  - Value Member : table1.code_value

In the WinForm.cs Code

```
//1. This code don't shows the combobox item
table1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonArrayColletion.toString());

//2. This code shows the combobox item
DataRow dr;
dr = table1.NewRow();
dr["code_desc"] = "one";
dr["code_value"] = "1";
table1.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Do you know this reason?

Comment: While you've provided clear, commented code, it's useful to provide a sentence or two of context to introduce your problem. People will spend their time to help you, so please take a moment or two to describe what your problem is. Also, if something is "not working", please describe what you expected to happen, and what is actually happening.

Comment: Thank your comment.
I'll retry.